# C# Web API jsonconvert.deserializeobject issue

Tags: c#, json, api, web

I am trying to read values from a JSON Response.  The EmpResponse shows me the correct data but the response object has NULL values for all fields.  Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
here is my Model

 
 
public class AlertMessage
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
}

public class ItemLine
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int BilledAmount { get; set; }
    public int PaidAmount { get; set; }
}

public class CitationDetail
{
    public string CitationNumber { get; set; }
    public string DefendantName { get; set; }
    public string DateofBirth { get; set; }
    public string VehicleTagNumber { get; set; }
    public string CaseType { get; set; }
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
    public string AppearanceDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsPayable { get; set; }
    public int FineSuspended { get; set; }
    public int FineServed { get; set; }
    public List<AlertMessage> AlertMessages { get; set; }
    public List<ItemLine> ItemLines { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<CitationDetail> CitationDetails { get; set; }
    public int CitationCount { get; set; }
    public bool SuccessfulSearch { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

here is my Controller for Details(int id)

Comment: Do you use Newtonsoft package? Microsoft Built-In JSON serializer/deserializer is not stable.

Comment: You should post the JSON her as text, looks like your object is actually a wrapper around an array of `CitationDetail`

Comment: I see a collection in the json string you have there, not a single object.

Comment: share your class CitationDetail

Comment: Next time please post the code itself, not a screenshot as we can read and cut'n'paste code, your image only captures some of the information.

Comment: I posted my Model - thanks for the help here

Comment: here is my Controller for Details - if you notice from the  Screenshot all values are NULL 
              `var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CitationDetail>(await 
        client.GetStringAsync(url));
               
        var empResponseObj =    
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CitationWrapper>(EmpResponse);
                return View(empResponseObj.CitationDetails);`

Comment: To complete the picture you need to post the json as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consume external Web API in MVC .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480179/consume-external-web-api-in-mvc-net)

Comment: In each of the posts you have made over the last 3 days you have been experiencing the same issue and do not seem to have grasped the solutions from any of these questions. Is this your code or are you coming in late to clean up an existing project? In any case, in the future please include a link in your post to other similar posts of yours and explain how this current post is different

Comment: While it is fun to help you with each line of code I suspect you could benefit from some mentoring or a team mate, something more one on one.

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks for updating the post with the classes!

Your JSON actually represents and instance of the `Root` class. So you need to change the deserialization script to use the `Root` type definition and not the the `CitationDetails`.

```
var empResponseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(EmpResponse);
return View(empResponseObj);
```

You can see a proof of this in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NvFIeu
Note that I could only replicate part of the json (the part we can see in the screenshot), but this is still enough to prove the point.

The result from dumping `empResponseObj` is this:

```
Dumping object(Root)
 CitationCount     : 0
 CitationDetails   : [
                    {
                    AlertMessages     : null
                    AppearanceDate    : null
                    CaseStatus        : null
                    CaseType          : null
                    CitationNumber    : 00007082303
                    DateofBirth       : null
                    DefendantName     : ALEXANDER. MASON CALE
                    FineServed        : 0
                    FineSuspended     : 0
                    IsPayable         : False
                    ItemLines         : null
                    VehicleTagNumber  : null
  }
]
 ErrorMessage      : null
 SuccessfulSearch  : False
```

If you only wanted to return the `CitationDetail` that has a `CitationNumber` that matches the `Id` that is passed into your `Details` method, then the following may meet your expectation:

```
var empResponseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(EmpResponse);
var idAsString = id.ToString();
var singleCitationDetail = empResponseObj.CitationDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CitationNumber == idAsString);
return View(singleCitationDetail);
```

> if the above logic matches your expectation, then you should check the API documentation to see if there is a route or query you can use to return just the single `CitationDetail` record that you need, rather than downloading them *all* and discarding all the data that is not needed.

Filtering this response in this method in unusual, it would be more efficient to perform the filtering on the API side. If passing in the `Id` to the route returns multiple records, then that is expected for this route. Either you need to pass through more parameters or you should modify the view to support the `Root` object instance that the API returns.

If the only parameter is `id`, then the response to this query:

```
await client.GetAsync("api/Juris/Citation/" + id);
```

Is all expected to be relevant and correspond to the give value of `id`, in this case it doesn't make much sense to further filter the results without being able to justify your logic.

> Please include the relevant values for `id` and some if not all of the JSON response. Then explain from that data which one of the `CitationDetail` records you expect to be returned and *Why?*

Comment: I only need to have a  View for the 1 record passed to the Details(int id) function - Do I still use the new List<CitationDetails>() ?

Comment: I tried your code and got this error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CPA.Models.CitationDetail]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CPA.Models.CitationDetail'.

Comment: You need a model that looks exactly like your json. It doesn't matter if you need only parts of it later. If you debug your code, you should see that the response data is now filled. The error looks like you are passing this model to a function that expects only parts of the response.

Comment: This is awesome guys!  I'm getting the data on the EmpResponse obj now

Comment: now I get this error on the Details page: Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'CPA.Models.Root', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CPA.Models.CitationDetail'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Thanks for your help on this! This is new and exciting for me to learn this web api world....

Comment: Yes well now you have to change that page, or change this method to return only `one` of the citation details. Because you pass the `Id` as part of the route to the service, we can only assume that _all_ of the citation details in the response correspond to the passed in `Id`. Only you have to documentation and knowledge on what you want to achieve here. If `Id` actually correlates to `CitationNumber` in the `EmpResponse` then you could return part of the response, but without seeing the full JSON I can't assure you that it would work. What value for `Id` are you passing into this method?